# Куда поставить ударение.

Tags: ударение

скрИптовый или скриптОвый язык программирования ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.seobuilding.ru/wiki/Скриптовый_язык

Скри́птовый язы́к (англ. scripting language). В русскоязычной литературе это язык сценариев.

Можно было предположить изначально, что ударение падает на основу. В этом случае русское произношение стремится передать без искажения новое слово script - сценарий.

Answer (score 1):

В английском языке ударение, как правило, падает на первый слог. Во французском, например, -- на последний. Это так, на будущее)